# CSS does not match where XPath does in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, css-selectors, nokogiri

I am trying to get some content from a HTML page. Here I divide the HTML into several parts and parse each sub-part using Nokogiri.

When I use the CSS selectors it does not match the sub-part where the XPath selector does:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'nokogiri'

# construct simple HTML
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div><h3>Heading</h3></div>')
puts doc, "\n"

# get the div
div = doc.at_css('div')
puts div, "\n"

# get heading using XPath and CSS. CSS doesn't match!
puts "XPath: ", div.at_xpath('//div/h3[1]') || "no match"
puts "CSS: ", div.at_css('div > h3') || "no match"
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div><h3>Heading</h3></div></body></html>

<div><h3>Heading</h3></div>

XPath: 
<h3>Heading</h3>
CSS:
no match
```

As you can see there is no match at the CSS part. So why does the expression `div > h3` does not match? Shall I create a new `Nokogiri::HTML` for the `div` variable (might be performance issue if I use this for large documents with many sub-parts)? Or wrap it with another element so that `<div>` is not the root element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//` in xpath mean **from root**; The xpath expression `//...` find elements from root even though you issue `div.at_xpath` ..

On the other hands, `div.at_css` find from `div` tag; no match.

`div >  h3` (css) is different from `//div/h3[1]` (xpath).

`div >  h3` (css) is similar to `.//div/h3[1]` (xpath).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about the root element. Using `div.parent.at_css('div > h3')` it works, as it consideres the `<body>` element as starting point.